# How to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1) = \frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

It is a exercises.
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
I know
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1) \le \frac{1}{4}
$$
by integral estimates. But I can't get the equal .

Comment: Not an answer, but in which book i could find exercises like this?

Comment: You may wish to use the fact that $$\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}\leq \sqrt{1+x}-1$$ whenever $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that Squeeze theorem says,

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\left( f\leqslant g\leqslant h \right) \wedge \left( \lim_{a} f=\lim_{a} h=\ell \right) \implies \lim_{a} g=\ell}}.$$

Letting $\displaystyle g(n):= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}-1 \right)$. We will show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} g(n)=\frac{1}{4}$ showing that for some suites $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ we have

- $\displaystyle f(n)\leqslant g(n)\leqslant h(n)$.
- $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} f(n)=\frac{1}{4}.$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} h(n)=\frac{1}{4}.$

Taylor series of mapping $x\mapsto \sqrt{1+x}$ around of $x=0$ give
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^{3}).$$
Hence
$$\color{red}{\boxed{1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}\leqslant \sqrt{1+x}\leqslant 1+\frac{x}{2}, \quad 0<x<1}}, \quad (*)$$
Setting $x:=j/n^{2}$, we have in $(*)$,
$$1+\frac{(j/n^{2})}{2}-\frac{(j/n^{2})^{2}}{8}\leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}\leqslant 1+\frac{(j/n^{2})}{2}$$
$$1+\frac{j}{2n^{2}}-\frac{j^{2}}{8n^{4}}\leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}\leqslant 1+\frac{j}{2n^{2}}$$
$$1+\frac{j}{2n^{2}}-\frac{j^{2}}{8n^{4}}\color{red}{-1}\leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}\color{red}{-1}\leqslant 1+\frac{j}{2n^{2}}\color{red}{-1}$$
$$\frac{j}{2n^{2}}-\frac{j^{2}}{8n^{4}}\leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}-1\leqslant \frac{j}{2n^{2}}$$
Hence
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{j}{2n^{2}}-\frac{j^{2}}{8n^{4}}\right)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}-1\right)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{j}{2n^{2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{(n+1)(12n^{2}-2n-1)}{48n^{3}}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}-1\right)\leqslant \frac{n+1}{4n}$$
Hence,

- $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac{(n+1)(12n^{2}-2n-1)}{48n^{3}}$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} f(n)=\frac{1}{4}$.
- $\displaystyle h(n)=\frac{n+1}{4n}$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} h(n)=\frac{1}{4}$.
- $f(n)\leqslant g(n)\leqslant h(n)$.

Therefore by Squeeze theorem we get,
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{j}{n^{2}}}-1=\frac{1}{4}}}$$

**N.B:** More generally, if $f\in \mathcal{C}^{2}(]-a,a[,\mathbb{R})$ with $a\in [1,+\infty[$ and $f(0)=0$ we get $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{j}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}f'(0)}}.$$